# Unusual spike in thread counts every midnight in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, access-log, thread-dump

**Application Context**: We are currently deploying an application based on `spring-boot:3.2.0` which involves REST-based APIs exposed to clients using `spring-boot-starter-web`, integrating with our datastore via `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` topped up by an in-memory cache based on `com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine` and uses `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka`.

**Issue**: Every midnight exactly at 00:00 the thread count of our application spikes and after that very few threads are terminated, leaving our application with incrementally increased threads every day and resulting in the restart of pods sometimes(suspecting this due to OOM as the mem usage increases).

[image]

**Observation**: During this time, there is little deviation in the throughput pattern for the REST-based requests or consuming pipelines of the messages.

---

**Attempt**: So, we tried analyzing the thread dump of our application and compared the dump over two different days. One of the major aspects visible was that there are a significant number of threads that are `timed_waiting` in our application.

[image]

stacktrace for these looks like

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-61" #37660 [37664] daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=38462.67ms elapsed=46889.40s tid=0x00007f2e0c0557b0 nid=37664 waiting on condition [0x00007f2ddf2fe000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@21/Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x0000000684f26058> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@21/LockSupport.java:269)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(java.base@21/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1758)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(java.base@21/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:99)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:33)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.runWith(java.base@21/Thread.java:1596)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@21/Thread.java:1583)
```

---

**Help Wanted**: But from here, we are currently lost in understanding which direction to look into. Looking forward to some hints from the community over:

1. Could one of the libraries mentioned have some default configuration to perform some task internal to JVM exactly at 00:00?
2. Based on the stacktrace of the dump, how do we figure out by what process was the object that a lot of threads are waiting for created? (additional info)

***Note*** - I can share the thread dump if that helps and further information as and when required for this application. As I said, this literally happens every night with our application.

---

**Update**: Web and tomcat properties overridden for the application in setup include:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
server.servlet.context-path=/places/api

server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%h %l %t "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i" %D
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true
server.tomcat.basedir=/var/log
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=places
server.tomcat.accesslog.max-days=7
```

Comment: What are the names of the threads that keep piling up? Are these all like `http-nio-8080-exec`? Does the application have any non-default configuration regarding spring-web or tomcat? And in which timezone is 00:00? Is it the user timezone of the jvm or utc?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Thanks for your response. Yes, most of them are Tomcat-initiated ones like `http-nio-8080-exec`. The timezone is IST[UTC+05:30]. There are very few non-default configurations, updated them in the question.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker now that I doubled down on the configuration explicitly used for the application, could it be the log rotation? Is there a way to confirm that?

Comment: It looks to me like there's a sudden burst of HTTP traffic that causes Tomcat to spin up extra request handling threads. These threads will stop if they're left sitting idle for too long and Tomcat's thread pool will drop back down to its core pool size. Can you look at your app's access logs to test this theory?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I can confirm as already mentioned in the observations that the throughput of the application at this point does not correlate. Have verified that via the access log pattern too.

Comment: To those voting to close this as *"Not about programming or software development"*. It is pretty much related to programming tools used globally to apply to a wider audience. I am not sure, if there is a scope of improvement expected, but would appreciate a comment over that.

Comment: Does your code contain any `@Scheduled` annotations?

Comment: @Bohemian No, it doesn't and I have figured out the cause. It's the access log rotation! I could post an update with findings soon, but I am looking out for Tomcat's bug tracker for any existing references over this. Interestingly, their is a relationship with this when virtual threads are enabled impacting the [performance of the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77472556/poor-performance-over-spring-boot-application-after-moving-to-virtual-thread), that is what keeps me occupied with the proof of concept and more findings for now.