# Tomcat 9.0.80 with Open JDK (JRE only) v16.0.2 crashing/unresponsive several times a day with load: Thread Count hits Max and All Threads are Busy

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9, java-threads, java-16

Running Tomcat v9.0.80 using Open JDK (JRE Only) v16.0.2 on a Windows Server.

```
openjdk version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

It is crashing multiple times a day. The Tomcat process stays up but Tomcat is unresponsive. It is run as a Windows Service. This occurs multiple times a day and necessitates restarting Tomcat until it occurs again. From what I can see, it only occurs when there's a load. If there's little or no activity, Tomcat responds well.

From the Tomcat Management Console, I see that Memory is normal. There are no out-of-memory exceptions in the Tomcat logs. No DB connection leaks. In my experience, DB connection leaks (failing to close a connection) can lead to memory leaks.

What I do see in the Tomcat Management Console is the Current Thread Count climbs dramatically in a few minutes, after the Current threads Busy Number climbs dramatically. Then it eventually reaches the Max Threads count and you get a 503 Service Unavailable and Tomcat has to be restarted. It's every single thread. Stage is all S (Service).

So, let's say the Max Threads is 200, Current Thread Count is 100, and Current Threads Busy is 0. In a matter of minutes, Current Threads Busy sharply climbs from 0 to 100. Then Current Thread Count goes to 101 and Current Threads Busy goes to 101. The two are in-sync, as the threads are busy and the web server is hanging but not HTTP 503 just yet. Both Current Threads Count and Current Threads Busy eventually reach the threshold of 200 and then the web server reports HTT 503 Service Unavailable.

This happens multiple times a day but only with a load. Not sure what is causing it yet. I think the Threads is a symptom of the real problem(s), whatever that may be.

Any ideas on what this could be and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you taken a thread dump?

Comment: Not yet. It's a Production system on a different domain with a firewall between me and my computer. So I don't think JMX remote will work but I haven't tried. Any tools you can recommend to take a thread dump from the server itself? It's using openJDK. I don't recall if that includes the JDK or if it's only JRE use.

Comment: Why is a production system running with a short lived JDK 16 that had its end of life in 2021? `503 Service Unavailable and Tomcat has to be restarted.`  has it crashed or it is unresponsive? Identify correctly the issue. Troubleshooting this kind of issue requires information that we don't have, starting by the thread dumps. It is not even clear that this problem is on topic. This is a support issue with no programming relationship established yet.

Comment: Maybe it's a DOS attack? Maybe something inside the application is using too many threads or just waiting infinitely?

Comment: You could try using JFR for creating the thread dump or maybe it's even possible within Tomcat.

Comment: Tomcat use to require a JDK, so it should include the tools to capture thread dumps. You'll have to find the way to connect to the system since we don't know your infrastructure.

Comment: @user717236 Asking based on [a recent experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78127250/unusual-spike-in-thread-counts-every-midnight-in-springboot-application) with slightly different setup, would you be able to review/share your application logging pattern as well? Is it by chance that the thread count spikes when there is a possible log rotation from your application?